# Silica gel to dehydrate soft cheese safely?

Tags: food-safety, dehydrating

To firm up a soft cheese round, I bagged in fine nylon mesh (nutmilk bag) and buried in silica beads in a sealed container in fridge.

'Aged' nicely in 3 days.

Any food safety issues?
ie brand of beads not labeled for food service.
Can I dry beads and reuse for this purpose safely?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Officially, you should be using food-grade silica gel to dehydrate foods; this is why some countries have a certification system that distinguish between food and non-food grades.

That said, though, many countries consider silica gel to be harmless enough that they do *not* distinguish a food-grade version.  And even the FDA, which recommends using silica gel marked food-safe, doesn't actually regulate it at all [as long as the weight of the gel is less than 2% of the food that it accompanies](https://www.accessdata.fda.gov/scripts/cdrh/cfdocs/cfcfr/CFRSearch.cfm?fr=172.480) (also, if you look at that regulation, you can see that some gels can even be used *in* food).  So, while you *should* use food-grade products where you can get them, the risk associated with using non-food-grade appears to be low.

The exception here is [color-changing silica gels](https://deltaadsorbents.com/what-is-the-difference-between-white-blue-and-orange-silica-gel/). If the gel you used is blue or orange and changes color in the presence of moisture, it has highly toxic substances (like cobalt) that should be nowhere near food.

Comment: drying and reusing, any risk?